# change python.exe filename in anaconda environment

Tags: python, conda, anaconda3

I am running python 2.7 and python 3.8 on one machine. I have recently installed anaconda and this has updated the default python version to 3.8. I want to set the default on the machine to python 2.7 but user python 3.8 for anaconda and Jupyter notebooks. I have set the PATH variable to "python3" and changed the name of the python.exe file for 3.8 to python3.exe. How do I change the environment variable in conda to point to the file python3.exe?

Comment: I strongly suggest reading more about [how Conda works](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html), in particular, activating a Conda environment. The default Conda installation already behaves exactly how you've described. Namely, when an environment is activated, the environment's Python will be prioritized on the `PATH`, but otherwise whatever else is on `PATH` will be found. The only additional detail I would recommend is not to use `python3` or `python2`; simply use `python` and let Conda do the work of managing `PATH`.

Comment: unfortunately, i need to have both Python3 and Python2 on the machine for now, while i upgrade a number of scripts to python3.

Comment: Sorry, I realize my first comment may have been confusing. To clarify, when I stated "python2" or "python3", I was specifically referencing the aliases and not the Python versions *per se*. Conda lets one maintain multiple versions of Python by isolating them in separate environments rather than having to manually create aliases or manipulate `PATH` (it does all that under the hood). Whenever an environment is activated, the corresponding Python will always be accessible as simply `python`. The general point is that Conda is an engineered solution to the problem, so no need to roll your own.

Comment: The issue i have is that the machine is shared, I can only install conda under my username and i've developed new scripts under 3.8 other users access and run are developed using python 2.7. I have renamed the python.exe for python 3.8 to python3 and pointed to this in the environment varial so as not to impact the python 2 scripts. If users want to run a python 3 script they can by calling python3.exe but as i've now changed this, it's breaking conda.